# Mongo not returning full data from query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am using PyMongo and Mongo version db version v1.4.1, pdfile version
4.5

When I try to query the database I am always getting different
results. The code looks like this:

```
familycollection = conn.picdata
pics = familycollection[place]
pictures = [i for i in pics.find()]
return pictures
```

However pictures doesn't full return all my data. There are 8 total
elements in the collection and I am getting sometimes a full response
and other times a small response.

```
>>> len(pictures)
4
>>> pics.count()
5
>>> for i in range(10):
...     pics.count()
...
5
5
5
6
7
8
8
8
8
8
```

Any help?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

After working on this for a while I realized I was doing the reads too fast and needed to wait a little time.

James

Answer (score 0):

If your read is using an index and your scan has already started and during that time there is another thread that comes and inserts a document mongo will not be able to read that document. 
Reads may miss matching documents updated during the course of read.